# Delete categorical data from a column and leave the numerical data only ? I want to delete the word "SUBM-" from "SUBM-1245" IN PHYTON

Tags: python

I have a column in phyton which data type is object but I want to change it to integer.
The records on that column show :
SUBM - 4562
SUBM - 4563
and all the information in that column is like that. I want to delete the SUBM - word from the records and apply a similar function like excel "replace with" and I will add 0 to leave that empty with the numerical data only. Can anyone suggest a way to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (code - so we can reproduce your data in Python), and the desired output for that example.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Also, could you please clarify what you mean by "I will add 0 to leave that empty with the numerical data only". If we have `SUBM - 4562`, you want to keep `4562` only, right? I don't understand what `0` has to do with anything. I mean: you could convert to `04562`, but that won't be an `integer`, but a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `a column in python`, so I assume you are using pandas to parse your table. In this case, you can simply use

```py
df["mycolumn"] = df["mycolumn"].str.replace("SUBM-","")
```

However, you still have a column of type "object" then. A save way to convert it to numeric is this, where you basically throw away everything that can't be converted to a numeric:

```py
df["mycolumn"] = pd.to_numeric(df["mycolumn"], errors="coerce", downcast="integer")
```

If you specifically need integer values (float not acceptible for you in case of NaN) you can afterwards fill empty cells with 0 and convert the column to integer:

```
df["mycolumn"] = df["mycolumn"].fillna(0).map(int) # if you specifically need integers
```

---

Alternative is to extract all numeric values using regular expressions. This would automatically return NaN if the expressions do not match (i.e. also when `"SUBM-"` is not present in your cell)

```
df["mycolumn"] = df["mycolumn"].str.extract("SUBM-([0-9]*)")
```